# How to pass various parameters in URL using POST method in PHP

Tags: php

I have written some php code for uploading files in a php.
When I submit the code, it's working fine, now I need that filename in URL.
I know it can be done using the `GET` method, but is there any method to do all this using the `post` method?

```
$fname = $_POST['profile']['name'];
$url_page = "http://localhost/File_Upload/index.php";
$id = "43434343";
$url = rawurlencode($url_page);
$url .= "?file_name=" . urlencode($fname);
$url .= "&id=" . urlencode($id);
echo htmlspecialchars($url);
```

I have used the above code, but how it can be used to pass parameters in URL?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you want to send `$url` in POST field? I think you need to give more light on your question.

Comment: I need this - http:\\localhost\File_Upload\index.php?file_name=filename(which is chosen)&id=4343434343  when submit button is clicked.

Comment: Is you filename and id dynamic?

Comment: yes, filename chosen by user and with any new file ID is incremented by 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use base64 encoded url in your form as a hidden field [base64_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php)  like

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo base64_encode($url);?>" name="url" />
```

Now you need to [decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php) it on form submit code.

If your `id` and `filename` are dynamic then you can use [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax) and update your url from AJAX success callback dynamically like on change event of file name.